# How to track changes in Python?

Tags: python

For the code below, is "new" predefined by python? The code is confusing and I have difficulty understanding it. Can someone explain it?

```
int_range = widgets.IntSlider() 

def on_value_change(change):   
    print(change['new'])

int_range.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
display(int_range)
```

Comment: No, the `new` key in the `change` dictionary is not predefined by Python. It was chosen by the library authors [here](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Traitlet-events).

Answer (score 0):

Jonesinator has the right info.  I think that there's a lot more code that's not being displayed here.  For instance, "widgets" is not defined and will cause the script to error out.  (Same for IntSlider...)

The fact that it's in brackets tells you that it's a value for an iterator, such as pulling a number from a list or a key from a dictionary.

Personally, I think that "new" is a poor choice of word. It's not a reserved word so it's technically usable, but there are better ways to make keys for dictionaries.  Even new_value would be better.